# How to hide side menu when user opens the particular modal

Tags: angularjs

I have a side-menu:-

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="left" md-is-open="sidenavOpen" class="md-sidenav-left">

<li class="noFocus" ng-click="showModal1()">
   <a>MODAL 1</a>
</li>
<li class="noFocus" ng-click="showModal2()">
   <a>MODAL 2</a>
</li>
.... and so on.

</md-sidenav>
```

I my controller:-

```
$scope.sidenavOpen = false;

$scope.showModal1 = function () {
    $scope.sidenavOpen = false;
     $('#modal1').modal('toggle');
}
$scope.showModal2 = function () {
    $scope.sidenavOpen = false;
     $('#modal2').modal('toggle');
}
```

I am closing the sidenav whenever opens a modal. But there are many modals in my application. So, doing this for each one is a quite lengthy work, Can anyone tell me the efficient manner to do this for all modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one function.You just have to pass a parameter corresponding to the modal number to the function and then just invoke the popup

**JS**:

```
$scope.sidenavOpen=false;
$scope.showModal = function (id) {
    $scope.sidenavOpen = false;
     $('#modal'+ id).modal('toggle');
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<li class="noFocus" ng-click="showModal(1)">
   <a>MODAL 1</a>
</li>
```

Comment: can u explain what is this $scope.sidenavOpen[id] = false; for?

Comment: You don't have to necessarily use that. I thought you were using different variables inside each modal function and triggering the value of the boolean. But in your case since you are using same variable i.e. sidenavOpen everywhere, this array is not needed.